# iphone / ipad VGA, External device Display

Tags: iphone, ipad, window, vga

In my app it has lots of videos and animation to present a view. Am implemented External display by using TVOutManager sample app. Every thing works fine except video part.

inside my application videos are playing fine but in external window it not showing anything is simply shows "TV is connected, Video is playing in TV" in a small window.

So how to resolve this.. how to display inside app video to external window.

any idea or am i doing something wrong here..

thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone, ipad VGA External Display - tvOutManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781144/iphone-ipad-vga-external-display-tvoutmanager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here am answering to my own question.

robterrell's TVOutManager will not play any video to external device by simply doing [[TvOutManager sharedinstance] startTvOut] and [[TvOutManager sharedinstance]s topTVOut];

here we have add the instance of player to tvoutWindow. 
[tvoutWindow addSubview:player's instance];

but here thing is the video is not displayed in device,
 but you can control external window player from device.

cheers.